# ActionDispatch::Cookies not setting Set-Cookie header in response but response.set_cookie does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, actiondispatch, rack-cors

I have a Rails 5 API only app and want to send cookies in the response of a JSON request. When I use ActionDispatch::Cookies to set a cookie in the response of the request it doesn't set `Set-Cookie` header in the response. Although `response.set_cookie` does work.

I also tested with making an `after_action` hook in the application controller, and what I saw is `Set-Cookie` header is not present in response.headers but cookies['name_of_cookie'] is present. One question I also want to ask is when do these cookies(ActionDispatch::Cookies) set header in response? Does it happen in rack?

### Requirement

1. We want to set cookies in CORS request.
2. We want to set cookies for all the origin's

### What is already implemented

1. The client send a request with `withCredentials`
2. In the response `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin (request.headers['origin'])>` are present
3. As it is Rails API only app we have included the following middlewares in the application

```rb
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, key: '_namespace_key'
```

### Question

1. Why ActionDispatch::Cookies is not working but response.set_cookie is working?
2. When does ActionDispatch::Cookies set headers in response? Does it happen in any `after` callback hook in rails app, or it happen in rack? Because until `after_action` in applicaton_controller the headers wasn't there.

### Strange

1. While in development env and on my local machine it works, but not in production. Does it have to do something with the `domain` setting of cookie? I also use secure and httponly cookie in production, but only httponly in development.

What am I missing here? I have spend days searching for the problem but I couldn't find a fix. Any lead will be very helpful. Thanks

---

### Edit 1

```rb
cookies[@name.to_sym] = {
  value: @value,
  expires: @expire,
  httponly: true,
  same_site: 'None',
  secure: false            # It works when I set it to false but doesn't work with `true` in production. In development env it works with either one.
}

response.set_cookie(
  @name.to_sym,
  value: @value,
  expires: @expire,
  httponly: true,
  secure: true
)
```

I observed one thing. If I set `secure: false` in cookies then it works in production but not with `secure: true`. On other hand `secure: true` works with response.set_cookie in production.

My request.protocol is HTTP. Is it possible that ActionDispatch::Cookies does not even set cookies if request protocol is HTTP and `secure: true` option is configured.

But I think `secure: true` is for client side. Like if a cookie is secure then browser will only send it over https protocol only. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the reason for this behavior. Actually other team deployed an `application gateway` on production. This result in the Rails server getting HTTP request which was HTTPS initially.

Now as I have marked my cookies to be `secure: true`, it looks like ActionDispatch::Cookies does not even send cookies in response to a request if the protocol is HTTP. It will only send if protocol is HTTPS. If I disable the secure by `secure: false` then it work or if I disable the application gateway then it work with ActionDispatch::Cookie.

It seems strange as `secure` is a client side attribute, but from behaviour of ActionDispatch::Cookies it looks like it don't even send cookies from server if protocol is HTTP and secure is set to true.

Although I didn't find any documentation of this behavior, but this is how it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue but cookie was being passed as an Header. Issue was with `session_expiry` which was getting set on initiation (`session_store.rb`) as it was from different `Time.zone` which forced the cookie to be removed by browser as soon as it got created.

Instead, I've used `expire_after: 20.minutes` which made it work for me.

Posting this here, just in-case anyone faces similar issue.